# Materialize.toast() doesn't work in pair with tabs content

Tags: materialize

I can't make it work both Tabs and Toast
It doesnt appeared when content exist
http://screencloud.net/v/jMs4
and Toast shows normal if i delete content from DOM
http://screencloud.net/v/3MS0

Comment: Please post your code, not screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have issue solved. Just investigation by deleting some content from page and call Materialize.toast() again. so i found that in one node somehow exist tag  it is appeared here by some copy-paste. this tag was on collapsed content, so toast why Toast wasn't visible